# Update multiple records in SQL using Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Hello I doing an update from Excel to SQL but the code only works for 1 row. I want to update multiple rows or you could say all rows which are on Excel I have loaded

see the below code

```
VBA Code:
Sub UpdateTable()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim uSQL As String

Dim LR, LC As Long
Dim Group, Category As String
Dim itcode As Integer
' this is only for active cell i want for all cell in sheet which is on A column
Dim rngname As Range
Set rngname = ActiveCell
Set cnn = New Connection
        itcode = ShCustomers.Cells(rngname.row, 1)
        Group = "'" & ShCustomers.Cells(rngname.row, 2) & "'"
         Category = "'" & ShCustomers.Cells(rngname.row, 3) & "'"
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=MAK-SYS;Initial Catalog=db_bckupserver_test_sys;User ID=sa;Password=Rehman@123;Trusted_Connection=No"
cnn.Open cnnstr
uSQL = "UPDATE mak_items_chart SET [Group] = " & Group & " WHERE itcode =  " & itcode
cnn.Execute uSQL
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I want to loop it but I don't understand how I can add a loop which will update all the records into SQL

Here is the image with modified code

[Please see the below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlFXM.jpg)

Comment: No Active sheet is shcustomers sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that we only need the sheet with the codename `ShCustomers`. Then my suggestion would be

```
Sub UpdateTable()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim uSQL As String

    Dim LR, LC As Long
    Dim Group As String, Category As String  ' I fixed the declaration
    Dim itcode As Integer
    Dim rngname As Range
    
    Set cnn = New Connection
    cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=MAK-SYS;Initial Catalog=db_bckupserver_test_sys;User ID=sa;Password=Rehman@123;Trusted_Connection=No"
    cnn.Open cnnstr
    
    Set rngname = getColA(ShCustomers)
    
    Dim sngCell As Range
    For Each sngCell In rngname
        
        ' you have to check if the values make sense
        ' What about empty cells
        itcode = sngCell.Value
        Group = "'" & sngCell.Offset(, 1).Value & "'"
        Category = "'" & sngCell.Offset(, 2).Value & "'"
        
        uSQL = "UPDATE mak_items_chart SET [Group] = " & Group & " WHERE itcode =  " & itcode
        cnn.Execute uSQL
    Next sngCell
    
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

You need to add the following functions

```
Function getColA(ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim rng As Range
        
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = FindLastRow(ws.Columns(1))
    
    With ws
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))
    End With
    Set getColA = rng
End Function
Function FindLastRow(rg As Range) As Long
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    
    FindLastRow = rg.Find("*", , Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Exit Function

EH:
    FindLastRow = rg.Cells(1, 1).Row

End Function
```

Comment: I don't Have any Empty Cells

But it is giving me error on 

itcode = sngcell.value

Run time error 13

Type Mismatch

Comment: `itcode` is declared as `integer`! Do you have integers in column A? That's what I wrote in the comments of the modified code _you have to check if the values make sense_ Empty cells are just one case.

Comment: yes itcode is integer and i have integer value let me show you the image

https://www.mediafire.com/file/g89h6xydnt3j3gf/Screenshot+2022-09-23+141843.png/file

here is the image of my excel sheet

Comment: Please add the screenshot to the post. And also copy the value there. The error message says that the content of the cell is not an integer.

Comment: Error Image

https://www.mediafire.com/file/uwhbzbv1coz4p7i/Error.jpg/file

Debug Image

https://www.mediafire.com/file/n7425ccdncwrhqj/debug+highlighted.jpg/file

Itcode Value

itcode
13845
15801
8324
15802

Comment: So, the first value of `itcode`  is _itcode_ because you have a header in your range, right? This is not an integer. You wrote _' i want for all cell in sheet which is on A column_

Comment: Oh My God

Dear thank you i got That 

You are right My Problem is solved